# Can we use identifier function inside UDTF with its argument coming from the UDTF arguments in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here's an example how this UDTF should look like:

```
create function select2 (tname varchar, cname varchar)
    returns table (value variant)
    as $$
      SELECT IDENTIFIER(cname) FROM IDENTIFIER(tname)
    $$
```

When trying to deploy this function it throws a syntax error exception complaining about invalid expression after identifier.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDFs are not designed to create "dynamic SQLs". You can use identifier function but it should have called with literals:

```
create function select2 (tname varchar, cname varchar)
    returns table (value varchar)
    as $$
      SELECT IDENTIFIER('cname') FROM IDENTIFIER('yourtable')
    $$
```

It will not be different than plain SQL:

```
SELECT cname FROM yourtable
```

If you want to generate dynamic SQLs, you should use JavaScript stored procedures:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-example-of-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure

Comment: Any idea why they're having this totally stringent limitation?

Comment: Does that mean you can use identifier to pick a column/cname but not a table/tname within a udtf?